# DoubleList with template C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to code my DoubleList with head and tail, but during the compilation the compiler shows error:

> error C2664: 'doubleList::addFirst' : cannot convert parameter 1
>   from 'const char [4]' to 'std::string &'

Can someone help me?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class node{
private:
    T field;
    node* previous;
    node* next;
public:
    node(){
        previous = NULL;
        next = NULL;
    }

    node(T& name){
        field = name;
        previous = NULL;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class doubleList{
private:
    node<T>* head;
    node<T>* tail;
public:
    doubleList(){
        head = new node<T>;
        tail = new node<T>;
    }
    void addFirst(T& name){
        node<T> *newNode = new node<T>(name);
        if (head->next != NULL){
            nowy->next = head->next;
            (nowy -> next) -> previous = nowy;
        }
        head -> next = nowy;
        nowy->previous = head;
    }

};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    doubleList <string> *train = new doubleList<string>;
    train->addFirst("Ala");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In general, if you don't need to modify a parameter, make it `const`. This saves callers from having to work around a badly designed interface like `main` would have to do here. Also make sure to free all of that dynamically-allocated memory. `main` does not need a pointer or `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor, and also `addFirst`, take their argument by non-const *lvalue* reference, which means that it can only be called with an *lvalue* of the correct type - `string` in this case. You're trying to call it with a temporary *rvalue* constructed from a different type.

Change them to take their argument by value, const, or forwarding reference, and passing a temporary will be allowed:

```
node(T name)          // value
node(T const & name)  // const reference
node(T && name)       // forwarding reference
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to pass a const char* to a method that takes a reference to a std::string. The compiler is not performing an implicit type cast and therefore complains about a type mismatch.

Overload the addFirst method with another one that takes a const char*, explicitly casts the const char* to a std::string, and then passes it to your existing addFirst method.

Edit: Mike Seymour's answer is better than mine. This const reference example seems like it would be the best option in your case.

Comment: Implicit conversions from `const char *` to `std::string` work fine.

Comment: Yes, but implicit conversions from `const char *` to `std::string&` do not, which is the case here. However, as Mike has pointed out, implicit conversion to `const std::string&` work fine.

Comment: Of course, and it's implicit, so no need to explicitly cast it.